# Why a python package shows different versions using __version__ and pip (same directory)

Tags: python, pip, version

I have carefully checked the environment, and the two methods shows the same package directory:

```
>>> !pip show astropy
Name: astropy
Version: 5.1
Summary: Astronomy and astrophysics core library
Home-page: http://astropy.org/
Author: The Astropy Developers
Author-email: astropy.team@gmail.com
License: BSD 3-Clause License
Location: /home/duhc/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: packaging, numpy, PyYAML, pyerfa
Required-by: sdss-marvin, photutils, mgefit, gwcs

>>> import astropy
>>> print(astropy.__version__)
>>> print(astropy.__path__)
4.3.1
['/home/duhc/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy']
```

We see, the directories are the same, both are `/home/duhc/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, while the versions are different.

Comment: Because this might be a bug of the package itself, I have reported to their page [here](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/13475)

Comment: Which version does `conda list` report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not happen in a fresh environment:

```
$>conda create -n astropy python=3.9.7 astropy=5.1
$>conda activate astropy
$>pip show astropy
Name: astropy
Version: 5.1
Summary: Astronomy and astrophysics core library
Home-page: http://astropy.org
Author: The Astropy Developers
Author-email: astropy.team@gmail.com
License: BSD 3-Clause License
Location: ...\miniconda3\envs\astropy\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, packaging, pyerfa, PyYAML
Required-by:

$>python -c "import astropy; print(astropy.__version__)"
5.1
```

Also does not happen when the package is installed from pypi

```
$>conda uninstall astropy
$>pip install astropy
$>python -c "import astropy; print(astropy.__version__)"
5.1

$>pip show astropy
Name: astropy
Version: 5.1
Summary: Astronomy and astrophysics core library
Home-page: http://astropy.org
Author: The Astropy Developers
Author-email: astropy.team@gmail.com
License: BSD 3-Clause License
Location: ...\miniconda3\envs\astropy\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, packaging, pyerfa, PyYAML
Required-by:
```

What probably happened is that you overwrote a pip installed package with conda. Complete steps to reproduce:

```
$> conda create -n astropy python=3.9.7
$> conda activate astropy
$> pip install astropy
$> pip show astropy
Name: astropy
Version: 5.1
Summary: Astronomy and astrophysics core library
Home-page: http://astropy.org
Author: The Astropy Developers
Author-email: astropy.team@gmail.com
License: BSD 3-Clause License
Location: ...\miniconda3\envs\astropy\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, packaging, pyerfa, PyYAML
Required-by:
$> conda install astropy==4.3.1
$> pip show astropy
Name: astropy
Version: 5.1
Summary: Astronomy and astrophysics core library
Home-page: http://astropy.org
Author: The Astropy Developers
Author-email: astropy.team@gmail.com
License: BSD 3-Clause License
Location: ...\miniconda3\envs\astropy\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, packaging, pyerfa, PyYAML
Required-by:

$> python -c "import astropy; print(astropy.__version__)"
4.3.1
```

Therefore it looks like this is not a bug of the package, but rather a good example of why you should be careful to not mix `conda` and `pip` commands in the same environment without care. I would especially advice against doing so in your base environment (personally, I would not change the base env at all, except for updates).

Comment: The odd thing is that when I use `conda list | grep astropy`, it shows: `astropy 5.1 pypi_0 pypi`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think the problem is from the astropy version embedded in Anaconda. It will not be a problem when I use miniconda instead.